# Best way to monitor Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, system-monitoring

I'm working at a company that provides our small business clients with IT support. One of my tasks is to perform service checks which includes checking the event viewer for critical errors/warnings as well as DHCP and DNS management consoles. The event viewer for the clients' workstations are also checked but not as regularly.

Is there an existing solution that can centralize viewing of all these logs so that I do not have to remotely access each server and do the same thing over and over for each client?

Each client has some version of Windows server - from 2003 to 2012 R2.

Comment: `Is there an existing solution that can centralize viewing of all these logs so that I do not have to remotely access each server and do the same thing over and over for each client?` - Yes there is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Event Log Consolidator
View, consolidate, and dismiss event logs and correlate issues across multiple systems

Tired of having to open Event Viewer and connect to each Windows system to see its event logs? Don’t have a centralized way to view events from multiple servers?

Download SolarWinds Event Log Consolidator to organize event logs from several Windows systems in one view. You can view, consolidate, and dismiss event logs, as well as correlate issues from one central location.

http://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/event-log-consolidator

I use this everyday its actually very good.

Take a little IT know how.

And its free